# How to remove smart quotes from a string?

Tags: swift

I have a string like this:

```
let muString = "\n\nFebruary 11, 2012\n\nThis natural-color image showing Acme Inc\'s logo... bla bla bla “Mount Everest”... bla bla 'Black Viper' ... bla bla. \"Naja\""
```

In other words, I have smart quotes

` ´ ‘ ’ “ ”

(note: SO is not rendering correctly the previous characters. I mean they are opening and closing curly single and double quotes).

and also double quotes and I want to replace everything with a single plain ASCII quote.

I have created this extension:

```
extension String {
  func plainText() -> String {
    var newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{0060}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00b4}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2018}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2019}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201c}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201d}", with: "'")
    newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "'")
    return newString
  }
}
```

But doing

```
print (myString.plainText())
```

gives me the same as `myString` alone.

In other words, the extension cleans nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"gives me the same as myString alone."* - not quite. It gives `myString` back with any regular double-quote replaced with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `replacingOccurrences` returns a new string. Calling it on `self` inside the function means that you're always calling it on the original string itself. That means only your last call to `replacingOccurrences` is actually used. Instead of always calling it on `replacingOccurrences` on `self`, you should always call it on `newString`:

```
extension String {
  func plainText() -> String {
    var newString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{0060}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00b4}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2018}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2019}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201c}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201d}", with: "'")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "'")
    return newString
  }
}
```

Or you could just chain the calls directly which is a lot cleaner.

```
extension String {
  func plainText() -> String {
    return replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{0060}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00b4}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2018}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{2019}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201c}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{201d}", with: "'")
          .replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "'")
  }
}
```